# jquery select links in a class contain text

Tags: jquery, html

I have the html below:

```
<span class="srch-URL">
<a id="CSR_U_2" href="http://www.test.com/TestForm.aspx">http://www.test.com/TestForm.aspx</a>
</span>
```

I am trying to use JQuery to find all elements matching the class 'srch-URL' then change the link contained with them if they end in TestForm.aspx by appending  &Source=/default.aspx to the link.

The JQuery below would check all links containing TestForm.aspx

```
$('a[href*="TestForm.aspx"]')
```

but I need to do this only for if contained in the class 'srch-URL' then append the &Source parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$( 'span.srch-URL a[href*="TestForm.aspx"]' )
```

And if you're unsure on how to change the url, try:

```
$( 'span.srch-URL a[href*="TestForm.aspx"]' ).each(function(){
    $( this ).attr( 'href', $( this ).attr('href') + '&Source=/default.aspx' )
});
```